# How do I direct this to the correct location?

Tags: java, html, xml, http, servlets

I am relatively new to HTTP and coding in general, and I've come across the following issue.  I apologize in advance for any mistakes I make in asking this question, but I appreciate any feedback.

My (let's call him) instructor created a Maven project in Eclipse to demonstrate how servlets behave. In src/main/java I have the following class.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void init() {
    System.out.println("My servlet initializing");
}

@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Request received");
    super.service(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Post received");

    String parameter = request.getParameter("name");
    System.out.println(parameter);

    System.out.println(request.getReader().readLine());

    // We call our service
    response.getWriter().write("Hi there!");
    response.getWriter().write("Hi there again!");
    response.sendRedirect("http://google.com");
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    System.out.println("Get received");
}
```

In the web.xml file corresponding to this project, I have the servlet name set to myservlet. The url-pattern is then set to `/myservlet`. Now I have been attempting to make progress in understanding how HTTP works. Using Postman, I have gotten the TOMCAT server I am using to behave as expected with both GET and POST requests. However, the issue arises in the following html document I've created, called `form.html` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="./details">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="enter your name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I open this in Firefox, the form loads fine. I type in something random and submit the query. Since from what I understand this is a POST request, I figure the `action="./details"` bit will then refer to the servlet I defined up above, and specifically the `doPost()` method, which should in turn redirect me to Google.  However, it is giving me an error saying "Firefox can't find the file at `...src/main/webapp/details`." What is the issue?

Moreover, in the `doPost()` method above, what happens with the `response.getWriter().write(...)` invocations? I'm not seeing those anywhere after I submit something in the form of the `form.html` file. In any case, I'm utterly confused. A point in the right direction would be much appreciated.  If there is any additional information needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In your example `./details` is being interpreted as relative to where you have the `form.html` document saved.  When you say you opened it in Firefox, I'm assuming you meant that you opened the HTML file from your local folder. You need to navigate to the form through Tomcat.  If the form is saved in `src/main/webapp/form.html` then it will most likely be visible from `http://localhost:8080/form.html`

Additionally, if the url pattern for the sevlet is set to `/myservlet` then the action of the form also needs to be `/myservlet` to hit your servlet methods.

Comment: The `./details` part was a typo, I meant for it to be `/myservlet`. Okay, I will try that.

Comment: I went with your suggestion, and I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: What full URL to use to do GET on `myServlet`?  Is the 404 on trying to open the form or on submitting it?

Comment: To do GET, i'm using `localhost:8080/MyServlet/myservlet`. This works. When I typed in `http://localhost:8080/form.html` into Firefox, it immediately produced a 404 error:

"The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Comment: Without seeing your full configuration, I'd try `http://localhost:8080/MyServlet/form.html`.  It looks like `MyServlet` is being used as the context root (the root directory for the web application)

Comment: In Postman when I do POST on `localhost:8080/MyServlet/myservlet` it behaves as I would expect, and in the body returns the html for google.